# SQLite vs MemSQL vs other SQLAlchemy compatible in memory databses

Tags: sqlite, in-memory-database

What is the recommended in-memory database which connects to SQLAlchemy?

Requirements:

- Connects to SQLAlchemy.
- Minimal memory usage when empty (it will store <50MB).
- Easy to work with (e.g. Kafka vs RabbigMQ: Kafka requires much more user input/setup).
- Reliability in terms of the database going down unexpectedly.
- Can be accessed by multiple read applications.
- Shareable across a local network.

The two databases I've researched are SQLite and MemSQL.
Some points so far:

- MemSQL requires 8GB of memory, although I am unsure how much it uses when empty?
- MemSQL has replication however only in the paid version and not the free community version.

Input from users who have used these solutions or others is very valuable. Which solution would you recommend?